# Problema al usar INSERT INTO ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql

tengo un problema al utilizar la sentencia INSERT INTO ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE la cual utilizo para subir un excel con una lista de productos la cual deben actualizar a diario, y la sentencia la utilizo para actualizar los que ya esten e insertar los nuevos productos que esten en el excel. Las dos funciones las realiza de manera correcta, el problema esta en que el valor que inserta en el campo id de mi tabla al haber productos nuevos en el excel no concuerda. Aqui una vista de mi tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los productos del id 51 al 54 fueron los que actualizo, eso todo bien

El producto con id 109 fue el que inserto nuevo. El problema esta en que debería insertar el producto con id 55 y no con id 109.

Lo único que se me ocurre es que es como si estuviera sumando los 54 ids anteriores y hace el incremento a partir de ahí.

El codigo que utilizo es este:

```
<?php

require 'PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
require 'conexion.php';
header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");
set_time_limit(1000);
$nombreArchivo = 'lista.xlsx';

$objPHPExcel = PHPEXCEL_IOFactory::load($nombreArchivo);

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

$numRows = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestRow();

echo '<center><table border=1><tr><td>zip</td><td>city</td></tr>';

for($i = 13; $i <= $numRows; $i++){

    $cod = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A'.$i)->getCalculatedValue();
    $descri = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B'.$i)->getCalculatedValue();
    $uxc = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('C'.$i)->getCalculatedValue();
    $uni = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('D'.$i)->getCalculatedValue();
    $price = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('E'.$i)->getCalculatedValue();

    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$cod.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$descri.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$uxc.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$uni.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$price.'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';

    $sql = "INSERT INTO productos(codigo,descripcion,uxc,uni)VALUES('$cod','".utf8_decode($descri)."','$uxc','$uni') 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE codigo = '".$cod."',descripcion = '".$descri."',uxc = '".$uxc."',uni = '".$uni."' ";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

}

     echo mysqli_error($mysqli);

     echo '</table></center>';
```

La verdad no entiendo porque pasa esto, gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: El campo id_producto supongo que es un autoincremento, es posible que hayas borrado registros de tu tabla? Porque aunque los borres el campo de mantiene el valor de cara al incremento salvo que se lo cambies.

Comment: Si el campo es autoincremento, y he vaciado la tabla, he vuelto a insertar el primer excel y bien, luego hice el INSERT INTO ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE y bien pero me inserto el nuevo registro con id_producto 109, y volvi a repetir el proceso para agregar otro nuevo y inserto el nuevo registro con id_producto 165. Puede tener algo que ver que la sentencia este dentro del for?

Comment: No tendría que importar, porque solo debería incrementarlo al hacer insert, y por lo que dices te está haciendo correctamente el proceso de hacer insert o update. Revisa en opciones de la tabla el valor del autoincrement a ver qué pone.

Comment: hice el primer insert normal, y inserto mis 54 productos bien. revise las opciones de la tabla y me marca el valor del autoincrement en 109. osea que ya desde mi primer insert normal de los productos, me coloca el próximo id en 109. que podría estar mal

Comment: Que raro, la verdad es que no sé qué puede ser, es como si contara dos veces los insert. Ponlo a 55 a ver si te hace bien el siguiente insert, y a ver que marca el autoincrement para el siguiente.

Comment: El problema es que por cada intento de inserción fallido el valor de la columna auto-incremental es aumentado aunque la inserción no ocurra. Puedes hacer una prueba muy sencilla. Intenta una inserción fallida a propósito, que intente por ejemplo crear un registro duplicado, de modo que sea rechazada. Luego inserta un registro correcto. Verás que éste adquirirá un valor con un salto (el de la anterior inserción fallida). Para evitar esto debes cambiar la lógica del programa, verificando 1º si el registro no existe antes de intentar la inserción. De lo contrario tendrás muchos saltos ...

Comment: Lo que he comentado antes [lo afirma la documentación de este modo](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html): *(The effects are not identical for an InnoDB table where a is an auto-increment column. With an auto-increment column, an INSERT statement increases the auto-increment value but UPDATE does not.)*  o sea: *(Los efectos no son idénticos para una tabla InnoDB donde a es una columna de incremento automático. Con una columna de incremento automático, **una instrucción INSERT aumenta el valor de incremento automático** pero UPDATE no).*

Comment: Entiendo Cedano, he cambiado un poco el codigo y he utilizado la funcion in_array para ver si el codigo del producto que me trae el excel existe en el array de productos ya existentes y realize el update y insert bien, pero me sigue saltando los ids, lo que hice fue que si existe, hacer update, de lo contrario un insert. pero aun sigue el problema del salto de ids

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que has borrado tuplas de tu tabla,entonces el id sigue incrementandose por la ultima tupla que metiste y no la ultima existente. Deberias sacar el id de la ultima tupla insertada e incrementarla en uno. Y ese valor darselo al id de la nueva tupla.

Comment: Lo que me quieres decir es que recupere el ultimo id insertado y en el INSERT INTO le pase para que inserte a partir de ese id?

Comment: Claro recupera el ultimo id que haya insertado en la tabla, le incrementas uno a ese valor y lo metes en el insert into de la nueva tupla.